# In Qt main function, how does QApplication learn about Mainwindow?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

Looking at a simplest Qt Widget sample application that you can find from almost every Qt tutorial:

```
#include "notepad.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Notepad w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

There is one thing puzzles me. There are two major variables `a` and `w` here. `a.exec()` starts Qt's main loop, which suppose to interact with the main GUI component `w`. However, both of them live on stack and I don't see any code pass `w` somehow to `a`. So how does `a` be aware of the existence of `w`?
Does the constructor of `w` initializes a static data structure that `a` can access to check the top-level widgets?

Comment: There can be a global variable all components register to

Comment: There's an extensive [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qt preprocess your code and build the real c++ code before compiling, its at this moment QApplication wrap all Q object in the main.cpp file and build the rest of the code from it.

Comment: Please be more specific in your answers. The only preprocessor that I can think you are talking about is the [Meta-Object compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html). Please note that MOC runs only on header files and that it affects only `QObject` subclasses that contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro. This makes the premise of your answer incorrect. . .

Comment: preprocessing, not preprocessor. like "code generator" and yes, that MOC, that what its do, QApplication become aware of other Q object at this time and then add them as child object.

Comment: sorry, I think you are messing things up again, `QApplication` never take ownership of any other `QObject`s, can you provide any citation from the documentation for this statement?